# How do I avoid chapterwise bibliography from being printed in TOC in bilatex?

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, memoir

Using memoir class with daleif chapter style. I have one bib file and trying to get a chapterwise bibliography.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[refsection=chapter,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references}
\begin{document}
\begin{document}
   \tableofcontents
 \input{Preface}
\chapter{Mentors}
\include{ch2-generatingIdeas}
\include{ch3-evaluatingIdeas}
\end{document}
```

And this is what I get in the contents page. 
I want to avoid bibliography from being printed in the contents page. If possible, I would be happy if the bibliography were printed as just like sections. Can be this be done in `biblatex`?

[image: Contents]

Comment: Your code is not an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), so I didn't test, but maybe `\nobibintoc` could help you

Comment: How are you calling the different bibliographies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `memoir` switch `\nobibintoc` makes the bibliography disappear from the table of contents (there is `\bibintoc` for the opposite).

Since you have per-chapter bibliographies you probably also want a `subbibliography`, use

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[refsection=chapter,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\nobibintoc
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Lorem}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{Ipsum}
\cite{worman}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```